# htaccess redirection just if url has parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I searched for it. But I couldn't find what I need.

I have a url like

> mydomain.com/1hr6rry5

Currently when a user clicks on this link he will go actually to

> mydomain.com/profile.php?id=1hr6rry5

And if the url be like mydomain.com/ he will go to

> mydomain.com/home.php

I mean when url has a parameter he goes to profile.php and when there is not a parameter he goes to home.php .

By now I'm doing redirection with php, which looks so slow. I want to make it faster by doing it with htaccess.

How can I do it?

my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

my index.php for redirection

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['act_id']))
{
    header('Location: home.php');
    exit();
}

header('Location: profile.php?id='.$_GET['act_id']);

?>
```

Comment: First, the PHP that you provided does not do what you claim it does.  Second, do you want to match any pattern after the `/`?  Should `mydomain.com/home` go to `mydomain.com/profile.php?id=home`? If you only want to match and redirect certain patterns, you need to be clear about exactly what those patterns are.

Comment: No I want to redirect every pattern after my main domain to profile.php?id=parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only Apache configurations (and then, .htaccess), you can try this:

1. Url rewrite:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. To define "home.php" as a landing page (or an index) of your website, open your Apache configuration file for your website (for example, default.conf or apache2.conf or httpd.conf):

   ```
   <Directory /path/to/your/webproject>
       DirectoryIndex home.php index.php index.html
   </Directory>
   ```

Comment: And from my opinion, you should keep index.php as the first "DirectoryIndex". As you are using Rewrite Rules, you should rename "profile.php" --> "index.php" (remove your previous index.php file) that will "route" all your web application in PHP. Then, if "id=home", just include "home.php" into index.php

Comment: Into "index.php": <?php if ($_GET['id']=='home') include "home.php" ?>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for rule

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

include this in your rule for every request for your website will redirect to home.php please give detail if missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([./]+)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to include the page:

```
    if(empty($_GET['act_id']))
{
    include ('home.php');
} else {

include ('profile.php');
```

}